Is it save to share ios simulator .app file
i have a question about sharing an ios application .app file that will be able to run on a simulator
My procedure of creating this .app will be to enable "allow archiving for simulator" in edit scheme -> archive, then archive using "any ios simulator device" as target and then getting the .app from .xcarchive -> products -> applicaiton -> applicationName.app and then share this app.
My main concern is not to share/compromise my source code,
will this procedure (.app file) share or put my source code in danger ?

When you archive your source code, a binary file is created which contained the executable instructions for processor. It is not possible to obtain the original source code from the binary file.
